# How to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac {\ln(x^2-9)} {\ln x\cos(1/x)}$

Tags: calculus

I have a question with L'Hopital Rule but I am unable to solve the question.

$\lim_{x\to \infty}$ $\dfrac{\ln(x^2-9)}{\ln(x) \cos(\frac{1}{x})}$

Thanks

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: You can use at infinity $x+9=x-9=x $

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: you probably mean that as $x\to\infty$, $x+9\sim x-9\sim x$. These mean that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+9}{x-9}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-9}{x}=1$. As in [Asymptotic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x^2-9=x^2\left(1-\frac9{x^2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

First we start with $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\cos \frac{1}{x}}$ which is just 1. Now dealing with the other part.  $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln (x^2+9)}{\ln x}$ Both of these grow without bound so we get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ good news for L'Hopitals. $\frac{\frac{2x}{x^2+9}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+9}\rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2x^2}{x^2+9}=2.$